# How to remove file reference from Runner.xcodeproj

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, xcodeproj

I have a ruby code that uses xcodeproject that adds my Google-Info.plist to Runner.xcodeproj as a reference. However I want to remove the older reference because I get following error:

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/figengungor/Documents/projects/app_gmo/base/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist':
    1) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/figengungor/Documents/Base Firebase Files/GoogleService-Info.plist' to
    '/Users/figengungor/Documents/projects/app_gmo/base/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
    2) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/figengungor/Documents/projects/app_gmo/base/ios/GoogleService-Info.plist' to
    '/Users/figengungor/Documents/projects/app_gmo/base/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
```

Here’s how I add the Google-Info.plist reference:

```
require 'xcodeproj'
project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(ARGV[0])
main_target = project.targets.first
gsi_reference = project.main_group['Runner'].new_file(ARGV[1])
main_target.add_file_references([gsi_reference])
project.save
```

Here’s the me trying to delete but not being successful code(I’m not familiar with Ruby, tried to follow documentation):

```
old_gsi_reference = project.main_group['Runner'].find_file_by_path('/Users/figengungor/Documents/Base Firebase Files/GoogleService-Info.plist')
old_gsi_reference.remove_from_project()
```

Does anyone have experience with xcodeproject and can help me out?

Comment: Have you find a solution this issue? I'm facing a very similar one

Comment: I just delete the lines which includes 'GoogleService-Info.plist' from ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file. With my dart program not ruby.